# C++ (foreign) thread pool

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, thread-safety

I created a class which is some kind of thread pool. The difference is that it holds *foreign* threads. This means that the threads are created somewhere else and are then held by calling `holdThread`. Then another thread can call `executeOne` or `executeAll` to execute a specific function. At the end the threads can be released by calling `release` or when the object is destroyed.

Now I'm not entirely sure about the race-condition-safeness of my code. Also, Valgrind gives me a warning about `nextFunction`, but I think as the code is designed, it doesn't need to be protected. From my testings it worked fine as it is now.

```
#ifndef THREADCONTROL_HPP
#define THREADCONTROL_HPP

#include <functional>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <unistd.h>

class ThreadException
{
public:
    ThreadException(const std::string &str_message) : message(str_message) {}
    std::string message;
};

class ThreadControl
{

public:
    ThreadControl() :
        nextFunction(),
        running(true),
        totalThreads(0),
        busy(0),
        cv(),
        cm()
{}

~ThreadControl()
{
    release();
}

/**
  * Releases all threads
 **/
void release()
{
    running = false;
    nextFunction = std::function<void()>();
    cv.notify_all();
}

/**
  * Controls the current thread until release is called
 **/
void holdThread()
{
    //The busy counter needs to be set while waiting for
    //the condition variable in order to avoid dead locks
    //The very first time the busy counter doesn't need to be decreased
    bool needToDecrement = false;

    ++totalThreads; //Count total threads
    while(running)
    {
        //Wait for condition
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(cm);
            if(needToDecrement)--busy;
            cv.wait(lock);
        }

        //Execute desired function
        if(nextFunction)
        {
            ++busy;
            try {
                nextFunction();
            } catch(...) {
                //Rethrow all exceptions but set counters before
                    --busy;
                    --totalThreads;
                    throw;
            }
            needToDecrement = true;
        }
    }
    --totalThreads;
}

//gcc < 4.8 has a bug with lambdas and variadic templates
#if defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ >= 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ > 7

/**
  * Executes the function by one thread
 **/
template<typename function_definition, typename ...args>
void executeOne(function_definition fn, args ...a)
{
    if(totalThreads == 0)throw ThreadException("You need to have at least one thread");

    //Flag to determine if thread was started
    std::atomic_bool started(false);

    //Set function to start
    nextFunction = [fn,&a...,&started]()
    {
        started = true; //Thread "started"
        fn(a...);       //Execute desired function
    };

    //Notify one thread
    cv.notify_one();

    //Wait until the thread sets started to treu
    while(!started)
    {
        //If no thread was available wait until one gets available
        if(totalThreads - busy == 0)usleep(1000);
    }
}

/**
  * Executes the given function by all available threads.
  * Could also be executed bo 0 threads. The amount of threads
  * is returned
 **/
template<typename function_definition, typename ...args>
int executeAll(function_definition fn, args ...a)
{
    //Determine currently available threads
    int availableThreads = totalThreads - busy;

    //Count the amount of threads started
    std::atomic_int started(0);

    //Set function to be called
    nextFunction = [fn,&a...,&started]()
    {
        ++started;  //Tell the main thread that I'm started
        fn(a...);   //Execute desired function
    };

    //Notify all threads
    cv.notify_all();

    //Wait until all threads are started
    while(started < availableThreads);

    return availableThreads;
}
#else
/**
  * Hack for gcc < 4.8
 **/
template<typename function_definition>
void executeOne(function_definition fn)
{
    if(totalThreads == 0)throw ThreadException("You need to have at least one thread");

    //Flag to determine if thread was started
    std::atomic_bool started(false);

    //Set function to start
    nextFunction = [fn,,&started]()
    {
        started = true; //Thread "started"
        fn();           //Execute desired function
    };

    //Notify one thread
    cv.notify_one();

    //Wait until the thread sets started to treu
    while(!started)
    {
        //If no thread was available wait until one gets available
        if(totalThreads - busy == 0)usleep(1000);
    }
}

/**
  * Hack for gcc
 **/
template<typename function_definition>
int executeAll(function_definition fn)
{
    //Determine currently available threads
    int availableThreads = totalThreads - busy;

    //Count the amount of threads started
    std::atomic_int started(0);

    //Set function to be called
    nextFunction = [fn,&a...,&started]()
    {
        ++started;  //Tell the main thread that I'm started
        fn(a...);   //Execute desired function
    };

    //Notify all threads
    cv.notify_all();

    //Wait until all threads are started
    while(started < availableThreads);

    return availableThreads;
}
#endif

/**
  * Waits until all threads have completed their jobs
 **/
void waitForAll() const
{
    while(busy > 0)usleep(1000);
}

/**
  * Returns the total amount of threads hold by this class
 **/
unsigned int getTotalThreads() const
{
    return totalThreads;
}

/**
  * Returns the amount of currently busy threads
 **/
unsigned int getBusyThreads() const
{
    return busy;
}

/**
  * Returns the amount of currently available threads
 **/
unsigned int getAvailableThreads() const
{
    return totalThreads - busy;
}

private:

/**
  * The desired function to be executed
 **/
std::function<void()> nextFunction;

/**
  * A flag whether the ThreadControl is currently active
 **/
std::atomic_bool running;

/**
  * The total amount of threads
 **/
std::atomic_int totalThreads;

/**
  * The amount of currently working threads
 **/
std::atomic_int busy;

/**
  * The condition variable which is used to notify the threads
 **/
std::condition_variable cv;

/**
  * The mutex which is used for the condition variable to
  * notify the threads
 **/
std::mutex cm;

}; //end class ThreadControl

#endif //THREADCONTROL_HPP
```

Here is how it could be used:

```
#include "threadcontrol.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
ThreadControl c;
vector<thread> threads(5);

for(size_t i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i)
    threads[i] = thread([&c]() { c.holdThread(); });

string text;
while(text != "exit")
{
    cout<<"Type something (exit will exit)"<<endl;
    cin>>text;

    c.executeAll([](const string &text)
    {
        cout<<"Workerthread says "<<text<<endl;
        sleep(1);
    }, text);

    c.waitForAll();
}

c.release();

for(size_t i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i)
    threads[i].join();
}
```

Comment: You should probably look at this defect report: [Making std::function safe for concurrency](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4348.html), some of it probably applies.